# Laravel 8.61.0 - redirection not working after login

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have facing the issue for after login user page 404 error. Please check the below code and help me the issue solve.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/login','UserAuthController@login');
Route::post('/login-user','UserAuthController@LoginUser')->name('login-user');
Route::get('user/myprofile','UserAuthController@UserDashboard');
//Route::get('user/myprofile','UserAuthController@UserProfile')->name('UserProfile');
```

**UserAuthController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Users;
use Hash;
use Session;

class UserAuthController extends Controller
{

public function login(Request $request)
{
    return view('pages.login');  
}

protected function LoginUser(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'username'=>'required',
        'password'=>'required'
    ],[
        'username.required'=>"The User Name is Required.",
        'password.required'=>"The Password is Required."
    ]);
    
    $user = Users::where('username', '=', $request->username)->where('status', '=', 1)->first();
    if ($user){
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
            $request->session()->put('userId',$user->userid);
            //return redirect('user.myprofile');   
            //return redirect()->route('user.myprofile'); 
            //return redirect()->intended('user/myprofile');   
            return redirect('UserDashboard');        
        }else{
            return back()->with('fail', 'Password not matches. Please try again!!');
        }            
    }else{
        return back()->with('fail', 'This Username is not registered.');
    }
}
public function UserDashboard (){
    return view('user.dashboard');
}
}
```

After Login Page
http://127.0.0.1:8000/UserDashboard
404 NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0):

Hi Replace your code from

```
        return redirect('UserDashboard');
```

to

```
        return redirect('user/myprofile');
```

Comment: @Kudoslntech I have edit the redirect but same issue 404 message http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/dashboard. if any edit in rote page(web.php).

Comment: try to change the route. Add `/` before user like  `Route::get('user/myprofile','UserAuthController@UserDashboard');`  to `Route::get('/user/myprofile','UserAuthController@UserDashboard');` if it is not working then check the view file is exist on the same path?

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect with name route like:

```
Route::get('user/myprofile','UserAuthController@UserDashboard')->name('user-profile');
```

In Controller:

```
return redirect()->route('user-profile');
```

Also, make sure `user.dashboard` view file exist.